# Add self table foreign key in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have parent and child entries in same table, For differentiate i have added one column which have parent id.

description of table as below

```
create table temp(id bigint(20) PK,name varchar(50),parent_id bigint(20) references temp(id));
```

for Ex..

```
id | name    | parent_id 
------------------------
1  | text1   | null 
2  | text1.1 | 1
3  | text1.2 | 1
```

How do i maintain this table with hibernate save / saveOrUpdate ?

When i m going to save records in this table it has ID as auto generated so at the time of save i would get parent_id = 0 instead of actual ID.

Please give some needful Answers..

Comment: it was not relevant answer that i really need..!

Comment: how is your entity mapped, and how are you estabishing the relationship between the child and the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hibernate annotation here Supose i have two entity Question and Answer.

```
Question have :
    questionid
    name

Answer have :
    answerid
    questionid
    name 

Answer Entity contain :

   @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="questionid")
    private Question question;

Question Entiry contain :
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="question")
    private List<Answer> anserList = new ArrayList<Answer>();
```

Now you can set Answer before actually creating question like :

```
for(Answer  opt : question.getAnswerList()){
                    opt.setQuestion(question);

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, u are having int variable as Parent reference in your business object. Take an object of same business object as a parent reference.

e.g.

```
Class ParentChild
{
   public int id;
   public String name;
   public ParentChild objParentChild;   // Instead of public **int** parentID; 
}
```

Hope, it'll help you...

Comment: i already have done same thing...i am talking about save issue...i have traced query it could save but having 0 as parent_id instead of relative id.